# Pipeline Submission from App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a requirement to send Datastore Entities to a BigQuery table while at the same time doing transformation of the data.
My design so far as follows:
AppEngine Java application publishes data to a Topic in the PUB/SUB service - got that working.
Then have a DataflowPipeline subscribe to the topic and read the message. The transform is then done and result written to BigQuery. I have some sample code running to test this.

I have a crude Pipeline working from my local development machine which I can run - all working as demo code. This is run locally via 
`mvn appengine:devserver`

The question is now: How do you deploy the Dataflow Pipeline from Google App Engine? The development machine does not have access to the production environment, so I cannot get my Pipeline running on the Google Pipeline Service.
I have tried to submit this from Google App Engine, but received out of memory errors. This seems related to some authentication problem. From other post here on StackOverflow it seems as if this "deploy" from App Engine is not supported "officially".

How would one do this in production environment then?

Environment dependancies so far:
maven 3.3.0
Google AppEngine 1.9.28
Google API client 1.20.0
Java 1.7.0_79
Workstation - Windows 7
Google Development Environment : Gold Package 
This is my sample code to get the pipeline process running....

```
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setNumWorkers(2);
        options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);
        options.setStagingLocation("gs://pipeline_bucket2");
        options.setProject("projectname");
        options.setJobName("starterpipeline");
        options.setUpdate(true);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        p.apply(Create.of("Hello", "World")).apply(ParDo.named("StringExtract").of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                c.output(c.element().toUpperCase());
            }
        })).apply(ParDo.named("StringLogger").of(new DoFn<String, Void>() {
            @Override
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                LOG.info(c.element());
            }
        }));

        p.run();
```

This is my stack trace for the error when trying to run the code above:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection$BufferingOutputStream.write(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:586)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:55)
    at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:94)
    at com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent.writeTo(AbstractInputStreamContent.java:72)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1168)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:605)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory$1$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:1152)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:1146)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory$2$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:1195)
```

Comment: you know that datastore can be a direct input of dataflow right?

Comment: Yep - we opted for the PUB/SUB solution as we can also feed the data to other clients - so two solutions in one.
The problem is still - how do you deploy the "Dataflow/Pipeline definition" if you do not have access via a development machine?

Answer (score 3):

Dataflow uses a 64mb buffer when communicating with Google Cloud Storage when uploading your applications artifacts. The OOM can be caused if the instance your using doesn't have enough memory, for example if your using an [AppEngine instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#instance_classes) with 128mbs of memory.

Also note that the first time your Dataflow pipeline is executed whenever you update the module or AppEngine does an internal update, the Dataflow SDK needs to upload all the application artifacts that changed to Google Cloud Storage. Depending on the application size, this can take more than 60s which is the limit for a frontend instance request and can cause [deadline exceeded errors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried to run the local devserver with different memory settings, even down to 128M and always happyness. I have stepped it down from 1Gig to 128M in different configurations to test, but it does not seem to be a memory issue as during normal AppEngine processing.
The problem is during the running on the AppEngine itself. From what I have read it does not seem as if Dataflow and AppEngine is fully "integrated" - Dataflow is integrated with BigQuery, BigData, etc - but AppEngine is not in the list....so just wondering if this is not the problem

Comment: It sounds like you only tried the different memory configurations when using the local devserver. Have you tried a larger production AppEngine instance itself?

Comment: You are correct in that AppEngine is not fully supported with the Dataflow Java SDK at this time, other users have had success using it though.

Comment: We had tried using AppEngine with different memory configurations as well. Same result. Is the any specific authorization stuff you need to add to get from AppEngine to Dataflow? I have dumped the credentials using this bit of code and both variables are null. Suspect this is part of the problem 
'
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(); String token = credential.getAccessToken(); String serviceAccount = credential.getServiceAccountId(); LOG.info("token is >" + token + "<"); LOG.info("ServiceAccount is >" + serviceAccount + "<");'

Comment: Ah, default application credentials support for AppEngine was only added in 1.20.0 of the google-api-java-client library: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup

Comment: Please verify your dependency tree. For example, in Maven you can execute "mvn dependency:tree" to get a textual output.

Comment: Appologies for the late response - we had total network failure at the office this week.
Here is the dependency tree dump. It does seem to us 1.20 of the google-api-java...
[INFO] +- com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-dataflow:jar:v1b3-rev10-1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-proto-library-all:jar:0.4.150721:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.20.0:compile

Comment: The complete dependency graph file is here...
https://drive.google.com/a/celbux.com/file/d/0B0wHo7aoZ7foV2tDRDFZUEY3VVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you copy this method into your pipeline and see where it returns null adding some logging statements: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/blob/dev/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/DefaultCredentialProvider.java#L254 which gets invoked from here essentially https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/blob/dev/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.java#L190