# Running Google Dataflow pipeline from a Google App Engine app?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am creating a dataflow job using DataflowPipelineRunner. I tried the following scenarios.

1. Without specifying any machineType
2. With g1 small machine
3. with n1-highmem-2

In all the above scenarios, Input is a file from GCS which is very small file(KB size) and output is Big Query table.

I got Out of memory error in all the scenarios

The size of my compiled code is 94mb. I am trying only word count example and it  did not read any input(It fails before the job starts). Please help me understand why i am getting this error.

**Note:** I am using appengine to start the job.

**Note:** The same code works with beta versoin **0.4.150414**

**EDIT 1**

As per the suggestions in the answer tried the following,

1. Switched from **Automatic scaling** to **Basic Scaling**.
2. Used machine type **B2** which provides 256MB memory

After these configuration, Java Heap Memory problem is solved. But it is trying to upload a jar into stagging location which is more than 10Mb, hence it fails.

It logs the following exception

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute: exception thrown while executing request
com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.RequestPayloadTooLargeException: The request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/pwccloudedw-stagging-bucket/o?name=appengine-api-L4wtoWwoElWmstI1Ia93cg.jar&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=AEnB2Uo6HCfw6Usa3aXlcOzg0g3RawrvuAxWuOUtQxwQdxoyA0cf22LKqno0Gu-hjKGLqXIo8MF2FHR63zTxrSmQ9Yk9HdCdZQ exceeded the 10 MiB limit.
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:157)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:45)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:543)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:422)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:275)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:545)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:562)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:260)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1168)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:605)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory$1$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:1152)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:1146)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory$2$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:1195)
```

I tried directly uploading the jar file - **appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.20.jar**, still it tries to upload this jar **appengine-api-L4wtoWwoElWmstI1Ia93cg.jar**.
which i dont know what jar it is. Any idea on what this jar is appreciated.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: A few questions -- what SDK version are you using, and could you provide a job ID?

Comment: Can you share the exception you are getting? Are you seeing the OOM locally (on appengine) or are you seeing it after the pipeline has started? If the OOM is occurring on appengine, then you may be running into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647161/pipeline-submission-from-app-engine

Comment: I changed the appengine machine type to F2 and i am not getting OOM error now. But it is trying to stage files which are more than 10mm and it does resumable uploads. The upload is taking lot of time and i am getting execution time limit exceeded exception. Any idea on this.

Comment: @SamMcVeety My appengine SDK is 1.9.30 and Dataflow SDK is 1.2.1. The job is not created. It fails in appengine itself.

Comment: @Bharathi did you end up listing the _filesToStage_ to get around the appengine-api jar upload causing the failure?

Comment: @TomNewton Yes I did. I skipped appengine-api jar on fileToStage options and it worked.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Bharathiraja

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that if you use AppEngine on a [Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) you will not encounter the AppEngine sandbox limits (OOM when using a [F1 or B1 instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class), execution time limit issues, whitelisted JRE classes). If you really want to run within the App Engine sandbox, then your use of the Dataflow SDK most conform to the limits of the AppEngine sandbox. Below I explain common issues and what people have done to conform to the AppEngine sandbox limits.

The Dataflow SDK requires an AppEngine instance class which has enough memory to execute the users application to construct the pipeline, stage any resources, and send the job description to the Dataflow service. Typically we have seen users require using an [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class) with more than 128mb of memory to not see OOM errors.

Generally constructing a pipeline and submitting it to the Dataflow service typically takes less than a couple of seconds if the required resources for your application are already staged. Uploading your JARs and any other resources to GCS can take longer than 60 seconds. This can be solved manually by pre-staging your JARs to GCS beforehand (the Dataflow SDK will skip staging them again if it detects they are already there) or using a [task queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) to get a 10 minute limit (note that for large applications, 10 mins may not be enough to stage all your resources).

Finally, within the AppEngine sandbox environment, you and all your dependencies are limited to using only [whitelisted](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) classes within the JRE or you'll get an exception like:

```
java.lang.SecurityException:
  java.lang.IllegalAccessException: YYY is not allowed on ZZZ
  ...
```

**EDIT 1**

We perform a hash of the contents of the jars on the classpath and upload them to GCS with a modified filename. AppEngine runs a sandboxed environment with its own JARs, **appengine-api-L4wtoWwoElWmstI1Ia93cg.jar** refers to **appengine-api.jar** which is a jar that the sandboxed environment adds. You can see from our [PackageUtil#getUniqueContentName(...)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/PackageUtil.java#L254) that we just append **-$HASH**  before **.jar**.

We are working to solve why you are seeing the **RequestPayloadToLarge** excepton and it is currently recommended that you set the **filesToStage** option and filter out the jars not required to execute your Dataflow to get around the issue that you face. You can see how we build the files to stage with [DataflowPipelineRunner#detectClassPathResourcesToStage(...)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineRunner.java#L1125).

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion, Java Heap size error is solved. But facing issue with stagging file upload. I have explained it in edit. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. I filtered out appengine-api jar and it worked. It would be great if RequestPayloadToLarge exception is fixed. otherwise if any of the required jar is more than 10 mb, users will not be able to start the pipeline using appengine.

Comment: is there a simple way to filter out individual .jars without having to list all the resources in order as mentioned above?

Comment: Currently there is no option which you can configure to exclude dependencies. The only currently supported option is to list all the dependencies that you require.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the 10MB limit. What I did was filtering out the JAR files bigger than that limit (instead of specific files), and then set the renaming files in the `DataflowPipelineOptions` with [`setFilesToStage`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions#setFilesToStage-java.util.List-).

So I just copied the method `detectClassPathResourcesToStage` from the [Dataflow SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineRunner.java#L2896) and changed it sightly:

```java
private static final long FILE_BYTES_THRESHOLD = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB

protected static List<String> detectClassPathResourcesToStage(ClassLoader classLoader) {
    if (!(classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader)) {
        String message = String.format("Unable to use ClassLoader to detect classpath elements. "
                + "Current ClassLoader is %s, only URLClassLoaders are supported.", classLoader);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
    }

    List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
    for (URL url : ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs()) {
        try {
            File file = new File(url.toURI());
            if (file.length() < FILE_BYTES_THRESHOLD) {
                files.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | URISyntaxException e) {
            String message = String.format("Unable to convert url (%s) to file.", url);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message, e);
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

And then when I'm creating the `DataflowPipelineOptions`:

```java
DataflowPipelineOptions dataflowOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
...
dataflowOptions.setFilesToStage(detectClassPathResourcesToStage(DataflowPipelineRunner.class.getClassLoader()));
```

Comment: This helped highlight a critical thing for me: that the 10MiB limit is on each .jar file individually, not on the total size of all .jars.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of [Helder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5180989)'s 10MB-filtering [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35771459/150001) that will adapt to the default file-staging behavior of `DataflowPipelineOptions` even if it changes in a future version of the SDK.

Instead of duplicating the logic, it passes a throwaway copy of the `DataflowPipelineOptions` to `DataflowPipelineRunner` to see which files it would have staged, then removes any that are too big.

Note that this code assumes that you've defined a custom `PipelineOptions` class named `MyOptions`, along with a `java.util.Logger` field named `logger`.

```java
// The largest file size that can be staged to the dataflow service.
private static final long MAX_STAGED_FILE_SIZE_BYTES = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

/**
 * Returns the list of .jar/etc files to stage based on the
 * Options, filtering out any files that are too large for
 * DataflowPipelineRunner.
 *
 * <p>If this accidentally filters out a necessary file, it should
 * be obvious when the pipeline fails with a runtime link error.
 */
private static ImmutableList<String> getFilesToStage(MyOptions options) {
  // Construct a throw-away runner with a copy of the Options to see
  // which files it would have wanted to stage. This could be an
  // explicitly-specified list of files from the MyOptions param, or
  // the default list of files determined by DataflowPipelineRunner.
  List<String> baseFiles;
  {
    DataflowPipelineOptions tmpOptions =
        options.cloneAs(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    // Ignore the result; we only care about how fromOptions()
    // modifies its parameter.
    DataflowPipelineRunner.fromOptions(tmpOptions);
    baseFiles = tmpOptions.getFilesToStage();
    // Some value should have been set.
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(baseFiles);
  }
  // Filter out any files that are too large to stage.
  ImmutableList.Builder<String> filteredFiles = ImmutableList.builder();
  for (String file : baseFiles) {
    long size = new File(file).length();
    if (size < MAX_STAGED_FILE_SIZE_BYTES) {
      filteredFiles.add(file);
    } else {
      logger.info("Not staging large file " + file + ": length " + size
          + " >= max length " + MAX_STAGED_FILE_SIZE_BYTES);
    }
  }
  return filteredFiles.build();
}

/** Runs the processing pipeline with given options. */
public void runPipeline(MyOptions options)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  // DataflowPipelineRunner can't stage large files;
  // remove any from the list.
  DataflowPipelineOptions dpOpts =
      options.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
  dpOpts.setFilesToStage(getFilesToStage(options));

  // Run the pipeline as usual using "options".
  // ...
}
```