# Error deploying GAE flexible project with a Servlet calling Dataflow Pipeline

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to deploy an App Engine Flexible Environment Project in JAVA with just a simple Servlet that create a Pipeline to execute in Google Dataflow each time the service is called, BUT I always got the same error deploying from Eclipse or Console. Anyone who knows why this error is occurring ? Please Help!

Servlet Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/execute")
public class ServletPipeline extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws IOException, OutOfMemoryError  {

      BacktestingPipeline.execute();
  }
}
```

Pipeline Code:

```
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction;

public class BacktestingPipeline 
{
    public static void execute ()
    {
                //Create Pipeline Options for Google Cloud Dataflow
                DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);  

                options.setProject("[PROJECT_ID]");
                options.setTempLocation("gs://[MY_BUCKET]/temp");
                options.setStagingLocation("gs://[MY_BUCKET]/staging");
                options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);

                Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

                p.apply(Create.of("Hello", "World"))
                .apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<String, String>() {
                  @Override
                  public String apply(String input) {
                    return input.toUpperCase();
                  }
                }))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Void>() {
                  @ProcessElement
                  public void processElement(ProcessContext c)  {
                    c.element();
                  }
                }));
                p.run();            
    }
}
```

Error deploying to GAE:

```
...
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.452653    46 jvmti_globals.cc:352] Build time: Jun 22 2017 16:09:00
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.453889    46 jvmti_agent.cc:158] Java debuglet initialization started
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.454350    46 jvmti_agent.cc:192] Java debuglet initialization completed
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.509760    46 jvmti_agent.cc:203] Java VM started
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.515812    46 jvmti_agent.cc:213] JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMInit initialization time: 6068 microseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.516059    57 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:99] Agent thread started: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.516363    57 jvm_internals.cc:376] Loading internals from /opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent_internals.jar
[INFO] GCLOUD: openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-1~bpo8+1-b11)
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:08.712635    57 jni_logger.cc:31] Initializing ClassPathLookup, default classpath: true, extra classpath: [/var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes, /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib], config: null
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @277ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Setting umask=02
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Opened ServerConnector@4e04a765{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Setting GID=999
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Setting UID=999
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider: Deployment monitor [file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/] at interval 0
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:10.374073    57 jni_logger.cc:31] Total size of indexed resources database: 431735 bytes
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:10.665549    57 jvm_internals.cc:132] ClassPathLookup constructor time: 1957471 microseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:10.672448    57 yaml_data_visibility_config_reader.cc:33] debugger-config.yaml was not found.  Using default settings.
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:12.667318    57 jni_logger.cc:31] Debuggee gcp:271259282847:4fb4ffcfa9706933 registered: {"debuggee":{"id":"gcp:271259282847:4fb4ffcfa9706933","project":"271259282847","uniquifier":"1523BCAEC984DB9222692DCF325FC70185D7E805","description":"multibacktesting-2017-distributor-20170713t142425-402646356863159386","agentVersion":"google.com/java-gcp/@2","labels":{"module":"distributor","minorversion":"402646356863159386","version":"20170713t142425"}}}, agent version: 2.15
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:12.667506    57 jvmti_agent.cc:415] Attaching Java debuglet
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:12.667809    57 rate_limit.cc:143] CPU count: 1
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:12.667858    57 debugger.cc:100] Initializing Java debuglet
[INFO] GCLOUD: I0713 19:39:12.678215    57 debugger.cc:109] Debugger::Initialize initialization time: 10 ms
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15:20 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-13T14:39:30-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/262M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy (default-cli) on project testing-dataflow-servlet: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy (default-cli) on project testing-dataflow-servlet: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.api.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit(NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:30)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.syncRun(DefaultProcessRunner.java:211)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.internal.process.DefaultProcessRunner.run(DefaultProcessRunner.java:137)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runGcloudCommand(CloudSdk.java:193)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk.runAppCommandInWorkingDirectory(CloudSdk.java:136)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.deploy(CloudSdkAppEngineDeployment.java:90)
        at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
PS D:\Andres Ortiz\Eclipse Workspace\testing-dataflow-servlet>
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>com.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>testing-dataflow-servlet</artifactId>  

  <properties>
    <appengine.maven.plugin.version>1.3.1</appengine.maven.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.5</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.54</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-b07</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial.snappy</groupId>
        <artifactId>snappy-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.0</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
              </rules>    
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>      

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
              <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My app.yaml

```
service: [MY_SERVICE]
runtime: java
env: flex
```

I have tried this in the app.yaml, but it does not works.

```
resources:
  memory_gb: 2.0
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

Comment: Since the error happens during deployment of this code, that means the code is not executed at all, and the error is not specific to Dataflow, but is rather an error with appengine-maven-plugin. I am not familiar with it, but there's a bunch of results if you google for "appengine-maven-plugin" "non zero exit", hopefully some of them will help.

Comment: Also: have you tried deploying your app using the regular GAE deployment tools rather than the maven plugin - does it succeed then? (I'd like to isolate whether this is actually a problem with the maven plugin, or is it a problem with your deployment configuration) It would likely help if you also included your app.yaml file in the question.

Comment: @jkff I added my app.yaml to the question.
Could you please explain to me a little more when you said ""using the regular GAE deployment tools" ?

I have deployed to App Engine Flexible from Eclipse, and also I have tried to deploy directly from Console with "mvn clean package" and then "mvn appengine:deploy". But the error is the same.

Comment: I meant deploying using the gcloud app deploy command https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/testing-and-deploying-your-app . Seems like the maven plugin swallows the error output of the command and doesn't tell you what's wrong? then running the command manually would help (unless it is somewhere up in a portion of the maven output that you didn't include in the question - can you check that?) - I'd recommend also filing an issue at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin/issues about the uninformative error output in that case.

Answer (score -2):

It could be related with the exceptions you're throwing in doGet method. Try removing it. If the servlet is still not working it could be related with your Dataflow logic. Maybe it could also be related with the fact that you're not returning anything inside the doGet method.

I'll do a sequential testing from the beggining.

1. Test the servlet with just a Hello World. If it's not working is probably a configuration issue.
2. Test the servlet with your Dataflow logic. If it's not working I'll test it with commenting everything except the first line, then the first one with the second one and so on.

Comment: The error in the original question happens during deployment - none of the code gets executed, so it is not a bug in the code.

Comment: I have already tried almost everything you suggest. I executed the Dataflow logic and it works, that's is a simple 'hello world' of Dataflow. 

I deployed the servlet alone with just the doGet method, and it works. What I was reading is about something about the size of the WAR file. Because I have deployed the GAE project only with the servlet and it works, but when I simply add the dataflow dependency to the pom.xml (without any Dataflow logic) and I deploy again as a GAE flexible project it does not works. The docker container boots perfectly, but when the service is up this fails.

Comment: @jkff Exactly.
The problem happens in the deployment process.
Even I have tried one part of what this guy mentioned here, about the setFilesToStage in the DataflowPipelineOptions, but it does not works.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130899/running-google-dataflow-pipeline-from-a-google-app-engine-app